# Android Studio install Intel HAXM failed on win7

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

VT-d was also enabled on the BIOS(gigabyte interface),but VT-x not seen.

turned off Norton Security still fails.

Windows 7 SP1 always install fails

Are there any solutions?

cpu:intel i5-7500 3.4Ghz(Have seen supported VT-x by cpu-z )

error log event:

```
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM
Extract: checktool.exe
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       *  Yes
VMX enabled         *  Yes
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          -  Windows 6.1.7600
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
```

Comment: This error description does not mention any errors. Install the newest haxm (HAXM v7.7.0 at github.com/intel/haxm/releases). If any issues will occur during installation, HAXM installer will show a detailed output of what exactly failed.

Comment: @nevilad Reply as follows one floor, thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the latest HAXM (v7.7.0).

First Step, Run silent_install.bat.The command Line disappears quickly without any messages

Second Step, Run HAXM-7.7.0-setup.exe at Administrator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No errors in the log, probably an error in the installer, fill an issue at https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues.

Comment: @nevilad  it`s worked , recovery to windows 10 system. I think it`s lack Windows 7 SP1 Update Package!! thanks for your help!